# Splitting field of a torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $T$ be a torus over some field $k$ (not necessarily perfect). Is there
a smallest extension $k'$ of $k$ such that $T \times_{\operatorname{Spec}k} \operatorname{Spec}k'$ is a split torus over $k'$? If so, how do you prove it?

Comment: The absolute Galois group of $k$ acts on the group of characters of $T_{k^{sep}}$ ($T$ extended to a separable closure of $k$). The Galois extension of $k$ fixed by the kernel of this action is the smallest splitting field of $T$. 

(This is extracted from the first part of my now deleted answer; I am not satisfied with the second part).

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142801/splitting-field-of-a-torus